# openCL clEnqueueNDRangeKernel fails; does not return a listed error type

Tags: opencl

My application is doing image processing in an openCL kernel and writing output to an openGL texture for display.

I am creating the context, command queue, compiling the program and creating the kernel, sampler and 2D image objects without error. Everything is running fine with no reported errors until I try to queue the kernel for execution:

```
errNum = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(commandQueue, kernel, 2, NULL, globalWorkSize, localWorkSize, 0, NULL, NULL);
```

this call returns a value of -1000.

according to the online [manpage](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.1/docs/man/xhtml/clEnqueueNDRangeKernel.html) for clEnqueueNDRangeKernel, there are several values errNum could be set to (defined in the cl.h header file). none of these values match -1000.

Any ideas about this error?

---

I'm running on an Nvidia NVS 4200M gpu if that's relevant.

Comment: I assume errNum is a cl_int  type?  What are the global and local  work group sizes?

Comment: Platform? OpenCL SDK of choice?

Comment: @James: It sounds like he is using the NVIDIA OpenCL implementation with a GPU device. milky_joe, is it possible for you to post the kernel as well?

Comment: @James I'm running on a Windows box with a Nvidia NVS 4200M gpu chip. I'm running Nvidia's openCL sdk as well.

Comment: @TimChild Yes, errNum is cl_int. global and local work group sizes are of type size_t[2]

Comment: @ananthonline i'm not sure if i can for clearance reasons.  However, the kernel does run correctly when not reading/writing from/to a normal openCL image object instead of to an image built over an openGL texture. 
But I don't receive any errors when creating the images over the GL textures..

Comment: That makes me doubly sure you're seeing a CUDA error. Have you tried with the ATI implementation running on a GPU?

Comment: -1000 is `CL_INVALID_GL_SHAREGROUP_REFERENCE_KHR`. It's not listed in the man page because it's defined by the GL interop extension. This should be `#define`d in `<CL/cl_gl.h>`. I currently have (exactly?) the same problem... Did you have any progress on this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure, but it is possible that you are seeing a (negative?) CUDA_ERROR_UNKNOWN (used to be 999, but may have been bumped up to 1000) from the underlying CUDA libraries that nvidia's OpenCL implementation piggy-backs on top of. I have seen a CUDA_ERROR_INVALID_VALUE error pop up (look [here](http://openclnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/97338#1251570) at the first value in my ErrorCode enum) before, which is why I suspect this.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using cl gl interop?
see cl_gl.h:

```
#define CL_INVALID_GL_SHAREGROUP_REFERENCE_KHR  -1000
```